# Show that $\Delta u$, $\Delta v= 0$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f=u+iv$ be a complex differentiable function. Then $u$ and $v$ are harmonic.

My solution:

We have Cauchy-Riemann equations held: $u_x=v_y$ and $u_y=-v_x$. Now:
$u_{xx}=v_{yx}$ and $u_{yy}=-v_{xy}$. Adding both terms we have $\Delta u =0$ (from continuity of partial derivatives). The $v$ case is analogical.

Comment: this is perfect.

Answer (score 0):

A complex differentiable function is infinitely differentiable, so all the partial derivatives are continuous.

Comment: Because function that is C-differentiable have continuous partial derivatives with respect to $u$ and $v$? I thought that implication is only from left to right, I mean that if function has continuous partial derivatives and satisfies CR equations, then its $C$-differentiable.

Comment: Its the other way also. If a function is differentiable you can write a taylor expansion of it. And it will follow that all the partial derivatives exist and is continuous too automatically